# Excel formula or Vba to Sum of all lookup value from multiple excelsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help for the below scenario,

1. Sheet1 A2 has a date
2. Sheet2 and Sheet3 has dates in column A and numbers in column B

example as below,
[image]

I want to get the sum value from Sheet2 & Sheet3 B column for all the values in Sheet1 A2 if finds in Sheet2 & Sheet3 A.

Below is my formula which I can get the sum from Sheet2 but not able to do with both sheet2 and sheet3.

```
{=SUM((Sheet2!$B$2:$B$65500)*(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$65500='Sheet1'!A2))}
```

Please help in formula or vba, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just add the two?

In B2 of sheet 1

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B)+SUMIF(Sheet3!A:A,A2,Sheet3!B:B)
```

Comment: Damn! It is so simple and I never thought of it. Thanks a lot @Dan Donoghue

Comment: Happy to help, I cannot count the number of times I have spent time on a problem that was relatively simple, it's hard not to overthink things sometimes :)